# Graphical mode in phpseclib

Tags: php, linux, ssh, phpseclib

How to use the graphical mode -X in `phpseclib`

the manual method (terminal) is:

```
$ xhost +Ipserver        // xhost +192.168.1.6 <br/>
$ ssh -X nomtilisateur@Ipserver      //ssh -X jack@192.168.1.6<br/>
$ export DISPLAY=:10.0<br/>
$ xeyes<br/>
```

I need to use the graphical mode in script php

```
<?php<br/>
include('Net/SSH2.php');<br/>

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.1.6');<br/>

if (!$ssh->login('jack', '******')) {<br/>
    exit('Login Failed');<br/>
}<br/>
//echo $ssh->exec('xhost +192.168.1.3');<br/>
//echo $ssh->exec('ssh -X');<br/>
//echo $ssh->exec('export DISPLAY=:10.0');<br/>

echo $ssh->exec('xeyes');<br/>
?><br/>
```

Comment: The -X option enables X11 forwarding which phpseclib does not currently support.

Comment: is this option exist in the libssh2 library ??

Comment: Doesn't look like it: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php Something that's unclear to me...  what would you expect to happen when doing `$ssh->exec('xeyes')`? Like are you wanting it to return a jpeg image or some such of the xeyes program or something?

Comment: i'm expecting that the GUI of the xeyes application or another application is like calculator

Comment: like that http://www.google.dz/imgres?imgurl=http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/ub_06.jpg&imgrefurl=http://pplware.sapo.pt/linux/6-comandos-para-linux-ubuntu-para-dizer-wow/&h=319&w=587&tbnid=uEdYBZGfHO9sMM:&zoom=1&docid=ICz2lrhQxZ-qdM&ei=nkYHVdLIIJLXasLBgcgC&tbm=isch&ved=0CB4QMygDMAM

Comment: i try to execute a software for controling a roboot under ROS from remote machine (customer machine).                                                          i need a framework (in php) which allow me to launch some commands (ros commands ) in the server,                                                           then i have two connections  customer machine----> web server (http) webserver------> Ros machine (ssh),                                                        i need to see on on customer machine the result of my commands .                     that's my problem @neubert